# Xamarin clipboard has text always retruns false

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm just trying to copy a value to clipboard and paste it, but has text value always returns false. what am i doing wrong?

```
await  Clipboard.SetTextAsync("HELLO");
            if (Clipboard.HasText)
            {
                var text = await Clipboard.GetTextAsync();
                await DisplayAlert("Success", string.Format("Clipboard content is ({0})", text), "OK");
            }
```

Comment: What is the platform you are targeting ?

Comment: can you mention the full function

Comment: I just tried this code in my XamForms app and it works correctly, yes, please provide more information.

Comment: its xamarin forms, i'm trying to copy value of a certain variable in the button event function, but when i try this code it always return a false in the hastext value.

Comment: private async void CORAPROD(object sender, EventArgs e)
        { string token = AS._persistentStore.GetValue<string>(PersistentStoreConstant.ACCESSTOKEN);
                string gg = "";
                await Clipboard.SetTextAsync(token);
                if (Clipboard.HasText)
                {
                    var text = await Clipboard.GetTextAsync();
                    await DisplayAlert("Success", string.Format("Clipboard content is ({0})", text), "OK");
                }
            }

Comment: Even after setting the text, the hasvalue always returns false. I'm doing something silly, cant figure out what it is.

Answer (score 0):

Please be noted that Clipboard.HasText **only works** under Android 11(included), it has been **deprecated** in Android 12.Below is the official document for your reference:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/android.content.clipboardmanager.hastext?view=xamarin-android-sdk-12